# Excluding data pairs from a query based on a table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2010

I have a massive and messy database of facilities where there are many duplicates. Addresses have been entered in such a haphazard way that I will be making many queries to identify possible duplicates. My objective is for each query to identify the possible duplicates, and then a person actually goes through the list and marks each pairing as either "not a duplicate" or "possible duplicate."

When someone marks a facility pair as not a duplicate, I want to record that data pair in a table so when that when one of the queries would otherwise return that pairing, it is instead excluded. I am at a loss for how to do this. I'm currently using MS Access for SQL queries, and have rudimentary visual basic knowledge.

Sample of how it should work
Query 1 is run to find duplicates based on city and company name. It brings back that facilities 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6 are possible duplicates. The first two pairings are duplicates I need to go fix, but that 5 and 6 are indeed separate facilities. I click to record that facilities 5 and 6 are not duplicates, which records the data in a table. When query 1 is run again it does not  return that 5 and 6 are possible duplicates.

For reference, the address duplicates look something like this, which is why there need to be multiple queries

```
Frank's Garage, 123 2nd St
Frank's Garage LLC, LLC, 123 Second st
Frank's Garage and muffler, 123 2nd Street
Frank's, 12 2nd st
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to fix this is to create a master table of company names and associate this table PK with records in original table. It will be a difficult and tedious process to review records and eliminate duplicates from master and associate remaining PK of a duplicate group to the original records (as you have discovered).

Create a master table of DISTINCT company and address data from original table. Include autonumber field to generate key. Join tables on company/address fields and UPDATE a field in original table with this key. Have another field in original table to receive a replacement foreign key.

Have a number field (ReplacementPK) in master table. Sort and review records and enter the key you want to retain for company/address duplicates group. Build a query joining tables on original key fields, update NewFK field in original table with selected ReplacementPK from master.

When all looks good:
Delete company and address and original FK fields from original table.
Delete records from master where PK does not match ReplacementPK.

Comment: Well fortunately the data is external to how I'm editing it. So if I fix a duplicate record, I won't need to do anything in my access file because it will simply stop coming back with the next update.
As a thought for how I could store the duplicates: What about a mashed together key? So if record 111 and record 222 are identified as not duplicates, I can just store "111222" as a non-duplicate, and exclude that from the query.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by 'exclude'. Couldn't 222 be a duplicate with 333? Really need to review duplicates as a group and pick one to be 'official' value and others are duplicate to be eliminated. What does 'external to how I'm editing' mean?

Comment: 99% of the duplicates are going to be pairs of duplicates, we just have some outliers of egregious offenders. So if 111, 222, and 333 are duplicates, it's fine that it pops back three duplicates of "111222" "111333" and "222333." Once the first two are fixed, the third one will cease to exist. So if I identify that 111 and 444 aren't duplicates, all that needs to be stored is "111444" in the "confirmed not duplicates" table, and that table gets excluded from the query on the calculated field of KEY1&KEY2.

Comment: Well, your example data was a group of 4 duplicates so I took that as the norm. Try your idea and see what happens.